# Anything slider width

Tags: css

I'm trying to set the width of the slider to be 750px so that it fits within the Facebook canvas and doesn't bring up the scroll bars.

http://www.facebook.com/pages/GolfffffffSteadyyyyy/213226708784235?sk=app_315085095232861

I can't seem to effect the "element.style" which when I inspect it, it's set to 6032px.  How do I control/override the element.style?

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting your link, I've found that the problem is originated by the `.container`:

**UPDATED IT TO THIS CSS**

```
.container {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 800px;
}
```

This solves your issue.

**Also**, take into consideration that you are setting the `.container` with `width:900px;`, and the `#contentArea` where it is inserted as a width of `width: 851px !important;`.